# firefox 4 - comet iframe, pushes(javascript) are not executed correctly

Tags: firefox, iframe, comet

I have an application that uses forever iframe(comet), this is working fine in firefox 3.6. But in firefox 4, pushes(javascript code that is sent from server) are not executed properly means firefox 4 is skipping some pushes, I have checked with firebug, there is no javascript error. I have tried, but unable to find the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing similar problems when using streamhub. This seems to be related to Firefox' [speculative parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing).